# Site.master menu items

Tags: asp.net

In my Site.master, I have a menu.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" ItemWrap="true" Orientation ="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/AdminAcctInfo.aspx"  Text="Admin Profile <br/>Info" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/BUsersAcctInfo.aspx" Text="Business Users <br/>Profile Info"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/FMMPublication.aspx" Text="Publication"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/ComplaintReportForm.aspx" Text="Complaints"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/FMMAnalytics1.aspx" Text="Analytics"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/PollResults.aspx" Text="Sold Items<br/>PollResults"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/PollResults.aspx" Text="Contact Us<br/>Reports"/>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/PollResults.aspx" Text="Approve Business<br/> Users<br/> Scheme 0 members" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/PollResults.aspx" Text="Check Duplicate<br/> Profiles" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/PollResults.aspx" Text="Coupons"/>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

There are 10 menuiitems that three of the menu items are falling on the next line.
How do I adjust the width or the font of these menu items and have all these menuitems on one line

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your parent tag:

```
ItemWrap="true"
```

Maybe set that to false instead?

Comment: Yes, I have ItemWrap = "true"

Comment: What I'm saying is, you need to change that to ItemWrap = "false"

Comment: It did not  make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You may change the font size through CSS to fit all the menu items in one line. It will depend on your screen resolution but I think font size 10px will fit all the menus for a full screen browser. Here is the CSS. You may keep on changing the font size until you are satisfied.

```
 div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 0.8px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```